www-data can't write in dir, even if write permissions are set
Debian 12
php-fpm 8.2
Apache 2.4
I have permission denied on /home/website/public_html/var/cache when website try to write or rename
The cache dir is owned by www-data and group www-data with chmod 0755
I set to 0775, doesn't work
I set to 0777 then it work!
Why www-data can't write in this folder as he is the owner and have write permissions?!

When you set it to mode 0777, what was the owner of the files that got created?

Same ww-data!
But I found the solution : it was an incompatibility between prestashop 1.7 and php 8.2! I installed php 7.4 and now it works, the files are written in cache dir! But it is a great mistery why www-data couldn't write in the dir with its own permissions on!

Some OS use a www-data user and a www user.
